# SSL connect to MQ using .net mq client SSLV3?

Tags: ssl, ibm-mq

Currently I am having a problem connecting to the server due to the following issue:

When I tried to connect to the server, it returned an error: `MQRC_SSL_INITIALIZATION_ERROR`

Upon closer analysis via **WireShark**, I found that the Client is attempting to connect to the server using **SSL v2**, while the server can only accept **SSL V3**, thus rejecting the connection.

I checked through the document, but am not able to find any information on
what SSL version the .Net client supports.

I would like to check whether the SSL version is controlled from the .Net MQ
client, and if so, how can we configure to make it connect via SSL v3?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you please provide the details of MQ version (both queue manager and client)?

Comment: The MQ server is 7.0.1.5, and the .net mq client is 7.0.1.3

Comment: Are you sure it's a real SSLv2 hello, or an SSLv3/TLS hello wrapped into a SSLv2 one? Does the handshake proceed any further after the client hello, or does it stop straight away?

Answer (score 6):

I'm not sure I agree with your conclusion since WMQ has supported SSL V3.0 and TLS V1.0 [since at least V6.0](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv6/v6r0/topic/com.ibm.mq.csqzas.doc/sy10710_.htm) and possibly earlier.  This is more likely a mismatch of configurations between the client and server.  The procedure I recommend to resolve SSL/TLS issues is as follows:

My method for debugging SSL connections on WMQ is to progress through the following sequence making sure each step works before advancing to the next:

1. Get the channel running without SSL.  This validates that the channel names are spelled correctly, that a network route exists between the endpoints, that the QMgr's listener is running and that the client points to the right port.  You'd be surprised how many times someone mis-keys a port or channel name.
2. Get the channel running with the SVRCONN definition set to `SSLCAUTH(OPTIONAL)`.  This performs an anonymous SSL connection similar to what your browser does.  The QMgr presents a certificate to the client but the client is not obligated to send one back.  This validates that the QMgr can find its certificate and that the client can find its trust store and properly validates the QMgr's cert. (*Note: the QMgr will always request the client cert and the client will always send it if one is present. To perform this test, use a copy of the client's keystore that has the signer cert(s) but not the application's personal cert.  Copy the keystore and delete the personal cert from the copy. Do NOT delete the original!*)
3. Set the SVRCONN channel to `SSLCAUTH(REQUIRED)`.  This now requires the client to find its keystore (in the last step it required only its trust store) and to be able to find its certificate.  It also requires the QMgr to be able to validate the client's cert.
4. Set up SSLPEER or CHLAUTH mapping rules to narrow the population of validated certificates that will be accepted on the channel.

The difference between steps #2 and #3 helps to isolate the problem by testing the SSL credential exchange in only one direction at a time.  This allows you to identify whether the problem exists in the personal cert or the public cert and on which side of the channel.  Nearly all problems are sorted out in these two steps.

**UPDATE**
Notes to respond to questions.  There are two types of certificate used with SSL/TLS.  The personal certificate contains the private key and is the one that doesn't get passed around.  The public certificate is the one that contains the public key and can be given out freely.  The private key is held in a keystore.  The public keys (usually these are the CA's root and intermediate certs) are stored in a trust store.  In some cases, these are separate files.  For example, in Java and JMS the JSSE provider looks in the environment for variables that point to the keystore and to the trust store.  It is possible in Java and JMS that the keystore and trust store variables point to the same file.

In the case of WebSphere MQ servers and clients other than Java, the keystore and trust store are combined into a single location.  Often referred to as a kdb file, it is actually a CMS key database comprised of several files of which one is the KDB.  In this case "keystore" is actually shorthand for a combined keystore and trust store.  For the .Net client, set the keystore location and other SSL properties in the [MQEnviornment](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv7/v7r0/topic/com.ibm.mq.csqzav.doc/un10790_.htm).

In the SSL/TLS handshake, the server *always* sends its public certificate in response to a connections request.  The client then must validate that certificate by first checking the signature and validity date, then looking in its trust store for the thing that signed the certificate.  If the thing that signed the certificate is an intermediate signer cert (it has itself been signed by something) then the search continues up the signer cert chain until the root cert is reached.  Assuming that the server is authenticated, the same procedure is applied in reverse by having the client present a cert and the server validating it.

When the process fails in Step #2 we can debug using knowledge of the process above.  The QMgr must first find its cert in its keystore and present it to the client.  If the QMgr cannot find its cert, the result is errors in the AMQERR01.LOG file stating this.  Always look on the QMgr side first when things die in Step #2!

If the QMgr *does* find its cert then the next step is that client must be able to find its trust store and then within that trust store must find the necessary signer cert chain.  If this fails, there should be errors on the client side to indicate that.  For example, a common error when setting the client environment is to specify the entire file name, including the .kdb extension.  When this happens the QMgr looks for `[keystorename].kdb.kdb` which doesn't exist.  Another common error is that the personal certificate exists in the keystore but with the wrong label.  Non-Java WMQ clients look for the certificate by label name constructed from the literal string `ibmwebspheremq` followed by the user ID in lower case.  For example, if my user ID is `TRob` then my certificate label would be `ibmwebspheremqtrob`.  Note that this is the certificate's label in the keystore and NOT the certificates Common Name or other field in the Distinguished Name.

Depending on the type of client in use, these may be in the Windows error log, local MQ error logs or other location.  If you can't find client-side errors, [WMQ tracing](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv7/v7r0/topic/com.ibm.mq.csqzaf.doc/cs12880_.htm) is also an option.

Comment: 1. Connecting without SSL is successful.

Comment: 2. But failed at step 2 SSLCAUTH(OPTIONAL). Does the QMgr presents its CA cert from its IBM Key Managment keystore - Singer Cert section, and the client matches it in the client's IBM Key Managment keystore - Singer Cert section?

Comment: What is the difference between trust store and keystore, and where are they located. Please excuse me as I'm not familiar with the cert stuff. Thanks.

Comment: Updated response based on comments.

Comment: Both our MQ server and .net mq client are issued with the same CA cert, which were added to their .kdb signer cert section with label 'rca'. Is this setup and label naming right?

Comment: Step 2 SSLCAUTH(OPTIONAL) does not require the client to have its personal cert with the label ibmwebspheremquserID?

Comment: Step 3 SSLCAUTH(REQUIRED) requires the client to have a personal cert with the label ibmwebspheremquserID, which is passed to the mq server. Is the client's personal required to be imported into the mq server signer cert section? Many Thanks.

Comment: If I'm creating a personal certificate for userID 'usr', can I fill in both the 'Comman Name' and 'Distinguished Name' as ibmwebspheremqusr ?

Comment: Correct, Step 2 SSLCAUTH(OPTIONAL) does not require the client to have its personal cert with the label ibmwebspheremquserID because the client never needs to send its cert with that option set.  It is equivalent to your browser's anonymous SSL when you connect to your bank without needing to have a personal certificate. Step #3 DOES require the client to have a personal cert since at this point the client will need to send it to the server to authenticate. In most cases with SSL and MQ we want the client to authenticate as much as we want the encryption on the channel.

Comment: The cert label is nothing more than an index into the keystore entries so that you don't have to specify the certificate by its serial number.  Since you can have any number of personal certs in a keystore, the MQ client needs to know which of these represents the MQ identity.  It looks up the user ID its process is running as, derives a label based on that, then asks GSKit for the cert with that label.  The client doesn't care what the CN or any of the other DN fields of the cert are during this process. You can specify a CN=doesntmatterwhatgoeshere if you want.

Comment: "*The personal certificate contains the private key and is the one that doesn't get passed around.*". Here, "*personal certificate*" to represent the cert+privkey is an abuse of language used by some tools (and some users). Strictly speaking, the certificate is always the public part, the private key isn't part of the certificate.

Comment: Yeah, and I regret the usage but it's the phrasing used by GSKit and WMQ.  If I make the distinction with WMQ users, more often than not it bogs them down trying to reconcile the terminology from different sources. I've come to accept it as a necessary evil.

Comment: Can the the personal's cert label contains '_' ? For eg: ibmwebspheremqmqm_usr   Many Thanks.

Comment: The Infocenter doesn't prohibit an underbar character.  If it is valid in the OS, it should be valid in MQ.