# How to Set SSLv3 on Websphere?

Tags: java, web-services, https, websphere

I have a component written in Java, I cannot change, which is deployed on WAS 7 and tries to call web service via https. I am getting:

*Server chose unsupported or disabled protocol: SSLv3*

When I tried to call the same web service from SoapUI or java app (the same version of java as WAS) I got the same error, but it was easy to fix with:

```
System.setProperty("https.protocols", "SSLv3");
```

For some reason I could not force websphere to work. I set this property via console but the error was still the same. When I print system properties I see that it was set properly.

```
Java version: 
java version "1.6.0" Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (SR10 FP1)
IBM J9 VM (build 2.4, JRE 1.6.0 IBM J9)
```

This is the log file from the server. How to force it to use SSLv3 instead of TLSv1? Can I change it through the console? I was told that it works on the server, however I don't have access to the settings. What might be the case apart from settings? Different version of JVM, WAS?

```
[1/24/13 17:04:58:842 CET] 0000003e SystemOut     O WebContainer : 4, **WRITE: TLSv1 Handshake**, length = 57

[1/24/13 17:04:58:967 CET] 0000003e SystemOut     O WebContainer : 4, **READ: SSLv3 Handshake**, length = 74

[1/24/13 17:04:58:967 CET] 0000003e SystemOut     O *** **ServerHello, SSLv3**

...

[1/24/13 17:04:58:967 CET] 0000003e SystemOut     O WebContainer : 4, handling exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: **Server chose unsupported or disabled protocol: SSLv3**

[1/24/13 17:04:58:967 CET] 0000003e SystemOut     O WebContainer : 4, SEND TLSv1 ALERT:  fatal, description = handshake_failure

[1/24/13 17:04:58:967 CET] 0000003e SystemOut     O WebContainer : 4, WRITE: TLSv1 Alert, length = 2

[1/24/13 17:04:58:967 CET] 0000003e SystemOut     O WebContainer : 4, called closeSocket()

[1/24/13 17:04:58:967 CET] 0000003e SystemOut     O WebContainer : 4, called close()

...
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have an IHS(IBM HTTP Server) in front of your WebShpere?

**If not:**

To change the protocol go from the Domain Manager Console: Security > SSL certificate and key management > SSL configurations > NodeDefaultSSLSettings > Quality of protection (QoP) settings

There you will find a combo Protocol, where you can set this. If SSL_TLS that is de default is already set you can try changing to SSLv3 but SSL_TLS should be able to handle TLS and SSLv3 and maybe there's something else than WebSphere on the path to this service.

You will find detailed information at: http://www.redbooks.ibm.com/redbooks/pdfs/sg247660.pdf

and also : http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/techjournal/0612_birk/0612_birk.html#sec1

**If yes:**

Than the instructions would be different, let me know. :)

Regards.

P.S - Is this log from the WebSphere server of from the "client" I have a smell that what might be happening is that the "client" is the one that does not support SSLv3, looks like WebSphere wants SSLv3 to close the handshake but the client site does not support it. If this is the case you could try changing the protocol to SSLv2 but be adviced that it would be a security risk doing that.

Comment: This was the log from the server. I've already played with QoP but still the same error. In the meantime it turned out that it works somehow on 6.1 so I will check that previous version on my local environment. Thanks for help!

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if this helps, but...

[SSLHandshakeException](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21318567)

[Something Related?](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v6r1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.websphere.ihs.doc/info/ihs/ihs/rihs_v3ciphspec.html)

[Maybe some help here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12907472/ssl-connect-to-mq-using-net-mq-client-sslv3)

and 1 more...

answer was SSLContext ctx = SSLContext.getInstance("SSLv3");

[Thread here](https://kr.forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=1532467)

[Troubleshooting Websphere Applications](ftp://ftp.software.ibm.com/software/webserver/appserv/library/v85/BOS85R10.pdf)

Comment: The answer that I'm looking for is how to configure WAS to communicate with web service with SSLv3 protocol instead of TLSv1...