# Error while using SSL in MQ java client

Tags: ssl, ibm-mq

I wrote a Java client with SSL Configuration using IBM MQ V7.5 client and running Java 1.7. For this I refer *[SSL configuration of the Websphere MQ Java/JMS client](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/library/techarticles/0510_fehners/0510_fehners.html)*, But in the Create TrustStore step 8, I used self-signed certificates. (Because I don't have certificate of the CA, Where I Get certificate of the CA?)

My Client Java code is

```
import com.ibm.mq.*;
import com.ibm.mq.constants.MQConstants;

public class MQProducer {
private static final String qManager = "QM1";
private static final String qName = "localq";
private static final String truloc = "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\IBM\\WebSphere MQ\\Qmgrs\\QM1\\ssl\\trustStore.jks";
private static final String keyloc = "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\IBM\\WebSphere MQ\\Qmgrs\\QM1\\ssl\\keyStore.jks";

public static void main(String args[]) {
    try {
        MQEnvironment.hostname = "192.168.43.5";
        MQEnvironment.channel = "myChannel";
        MQEnvironment.port = 1414;
        MQEnvironment.userID = "Taneesha";

        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", truloc);
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", keyloc);
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", "123456");
        MQEnvironment.sslCipherSuite = "SSL_RSA_WITH_NULL_MD5";

        MQQueueManager qMgr = new MQQueueManager(qManager);
        int openOptions = MQConstants.MQOO_OUTPUT;
        MQQueue queue = qMgr.accessQueue(qName, openOptions);

        MQMessage msg = new MQMessage();
        String message = "Hello world";
        msg.writeUTF(message);
        MQPutMessageOptions pmo = new MQPutMessageOptions();
        queue.put(msg, pmo);

        queue.close();
        qMgr.disconnect();
    } catch (MQException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("A WebSphere MQ Error occurred : Completion Code " + ex.completionCode
                + " Reason Code " + ex.reasonCode);
    } catch (java.io.IOException ex) {
        System.out.println("An IOException occurred whilst writing to the message buffer: " + ex);
    }
  }
}
```

I got the following error

```
MQJE001: Completion Code '2', Reason '2397'.
Caused by: com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiException: CC=2;RC=2397;
AMQ9204: Connection to host '192.168.43.5(1414)' rejected. 
         [1=com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiException[CC=2;RC=2397;
AMQ9771: SSL handshake failed. 
         [1=javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException[No appropriate protocol 
         (protocol is disabled or cipher suites are inappropriate)],
         3=kasun-PC/192.168.43.5:1414 (kasun-PC),
         4=SSLSocket.startHandshake,
         5=default]],
         3=192.168.43.5(1414),
         5=RemoteTCPConnection.protocolConnect]
```

Please anyone help on this?

Comment: I'm using MQ V7.5 and running java 1.7

Answer (score 0):

What is the MQ qmgr and client version?  What is the Java/JDK version?
If you are using latest versions of Java 7 or any version of Java 8, the SSL Cipher you are using has been disabled/decommissioned.  Use a TLS Cipher.

**Edit**

The list of ciphersuites supported by MQ 7.5 is on http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_7.5.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q031290_.htm?lang=en
You can try any of the ciphersuite whose cipherspec starts with TLS.  Make sure the svrconn channel on the qmgr also updated with the correct cipherspec.

If you are just trying out MQ on your local machine and want to get rid of this, enable SSL protocol on the jvm.  http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/7u75-relnotes-2389086.html
Look for  /lib/security/java.security and comment/remove jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms (usually the last line).

As a permanent fix you should use TLS instead of SSL as they are a security risk.

Answer (score 0):

First, please see my answer [SSL connect to MQ using .net mq client SSLV3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12907472/ssl-connect-to-mq-using-net-mq-client-sslv3/12923120#12923120) where I provide an SSL implementation procedure that makes the process *much* easier.

In this case though the error message reveals the issue:

```
No appropriate protocol (protocol is disabled or cipher suites are inappropriate)
```

As Umpathy notes in his answer, this is often due to selection of a ciphersuite in the QMgr that is no longer supported by default.  Although it is possible to select the setting in the channel and the client, the QMgr will refuse to use it based on the settings of `SSLFIPS`, `SSLSUITEB`, environment variables, or the SSL stanza in the `qm.ini` file.  Please see *[CipherSpec values supported in IBM MQ](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.sec.doc/q120565_.htm?lang=en)* for the latest on which ciphers are supported and how to enable the deprecated ones.

You also ask *Because I don't have certificate of the CA, Where I Get certificate of the CA?*

The choice to use self-signed certs is not a matter of whether you can find the CA signer for a given cert.  If either side of the connection uses a CA-signed certificate, the other side ***must*** have the signer for that certificate in their trust store or kdb, even if its personal certificate is self-signed.

If either side is using CA-signed certificates there are a few ways to find the signers.

- ***Best*** way is to fetch the certificate for which you need a signer and dump the details. The `Issuer Distinguished Name` will tell you which signer was used. If the cert comes from a reputable CA, most likely it will also contain a URL pointing to the authoritative source for the signer certificate.
- Second-best way is to ask the party who administers the remote node to look in the kdb or jks and extract the signer certs used for its personal cert.  This is only for trusted parties though because anyone from whom you accept a signer certificate is trusted the same as a real CA.  However, for the case that the remote node is a QMgr administered by someone in your own organization you can generally trust them to provide the legitimate signer certs.

Finally...
Note that if you are using self-signed certs, the other side *must* add your public key to their kdb or jks in order for you to connect.  At the moment the two sides cannot agree on a protocol but as soon as they do they will validate each others' certificates.  At that point the debugging procedure I provided in the link above should prove *extremely* helpful.