# SSL/TLS handshake between Websphere MQ Server and Client

Tags: ssl, ibm-mq

I'm debugging SSL errors between Websphere MQ Server and Client using T.Rob's suggestions and need help understanding the SSL handshake ([SSL connect to MQ using .net mq client SSLV3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12907472/ssl-connect-to-mq-using-net-mq-client-sslv3)).

My WMQ 7.5 client application is C code and uses a keystore (.kdb). Utilizing a CHLTAB provided by the WebSphere admin. The WMQ server is running Java and the channel is defined with mutual authentication.

The article states that in the SSL/TLS handshake, the server always sends its public certificate in response to a connections request. The client then must validate that certificate by first checking the signature and validity date, then looking in its trust store for the thing that signed the certificate.

Here's my confusion:  Since my keystore on the client side has only the application personal cert, how does the client validate the public certificate sent by the server?  I have provided the Common Name of my application cert to the WebSphere server admin but nothing more than that.

Thanks in advance for the clarification!

Comment: The keystore on you client side has a personal certificate.  The personal certificate is a key-pair.  There is a public part and private part.  The public part can be used to verify trust of the server.

Answer (score 4):

The bit about "my keystore on the client side has only the application personal cert" is troubling.  That won't work.  The client KDB *must* have the server's public key.  If the MQ server has `SSLCAUTH(OPTIONAL)` the the server's public cert is all that's required in the KDB for the connection to succeed.

The first part of the TLS handshake is where the client validates the server's certificate.  The use of public/private key pairs is how the authenticity of the thing on the other side is assured.  In order for that to happen the server must have its own personal certificate and the client must have the public key of the root of the signer chain.  In the case of self-signed certificates the public portion of the personal cert must be trusted by the client.  In the case of CA-signed certs the CA Root must be trusted by the client.  Whichever one it is, the client *must* trust something used to sign the server's personal cert or that cert can't be validated.

The TLS handshake is symmetrical so the second part works exactly the same as the first but the roles are reversed.  Therefore, in cases where mutual authentication is enabled the **client** must have its own personal cert (because that contains the private key) and the **server** must trust whatever signed the client's matching public key.  If the client cert is self-signed the QMgr has to trust it.  If the client's cert is CA-signed, the QMgr must trust the signer.  Either way, the QMgr has to have a cert to validate the client in its KDB.

Following this logic, for anonymous client connections the required parts are the personal certificate in the QMgr's keystore (because it contains the QMgr's private key), and the matching trusted certificate in the client's KDB or for Java the Trust Store.  Neither of these is optional.

If the client is to be authenticated you still need the same two certs as for anonymous clients because that part of the handshake has to complete before the client is authenticated.  In addition, now you also need the client to have its own personal certificate (because it contains the client's private key) and the QMgr now needs to trust whatever signed the client's certificate - the client cert if self-signed or the signer root if CA-signed.

---

As a side note, There is also some confusion in the post because it says that "My WMQ 7.5 client application is C code and the WMQ server is running Java."  There is nothing in the queue manager that uses Java on the server side.  There are Java components installed to do things like manage JNDI objects and run the sample code.  In modern MQ versions Java runs the Web Console.  But there are no Java components in the QMgr itself and no Java components in the path of the incoming channel connection request.  That's all habdled by the QMgr's listener, agent, and other internal processes. So I'm not at all sure what is being referred to there other than that the notion of Java running on the MQ server side and participating in the TLS handshake might be a source of some of the confusion mentioned in the post.  ;-)

Comment: Thank you T.Rob for the detailed explanation. Working with the MQ admin we've successfully advanced through steps 1 and 2 in debugging the SSL connection.  In step 3, with SRVCONN channel set to SSLCAUTH(REQUIRED) my client app is triggering the following error:

Comment: Here's the error triggered from the client app (running V7.5 written in C on Linux):
 
AMQ9654: An invalid SSL certificate was received from the remote system.

I rebuilt the .kdb and inserted a SHA256 certificate (created by Venafi). Wondering if there's a compatibility issue with the type of CypherSpec (TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256) designated on the MQ server channel?

Comment: Unless you are using elliptic curve cipher on the channel, that cert should work. Tough to tell since it's not clear whether the error seen was on the client or server side, but assuming that's a QMgr error, sounds like you might need to walk the signer chain on the client to make sure the server has the right trusted signer.  Also, after updating the KDB, you did `REFRESH SECURITY TYPE(SSL)` on the QMgr or restarted it, right?

Comment: Actually the AMQ9654 error is only on the client side. The MQ admin see's no errors or sign of my client connection in the MQ server log. Turns out the CypherSpec is TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA which I can see in the AMQCLCHL.TAB. I'm stumped as to where the disconnect is. I'm looking to upgrade the client to 8.0.0.7 to get a better description of the error but that will take some time given the corporate bottlenecks. Any other thoughts or suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: If TLS rejects the handshake it's considered routine.  In fact, when I want to fetch the cert of a remote QMgr, I give it an expired client cert to make it close the connection without cutting an FDC. I would print out the cert details in the client and server keystores and manually walk the signer chain.  `runmqakm -cert -details -db keystore name -label 'cert label name' -stashed` would do the trick. It seems like a tedious chore I know, but I lived in Missouri long enough to acquire a "show me" attitude.  I can't count the number of times I've done this and discovered a mismatch.